# Firebase V9, add subcollection to existing doc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
const q = getDoc(doc(db, "customers", user.uid));
```

Hello, this returns a promise in the console.log.
I have a customers collection and each user.uid is a document inside it. I want to create a subcollection for each user.uid document, so I can put an object { with some parameters} inside. But how do I create a subcollection called "checkout_sessions" for each document(user.uid). Any help would be appreciated, please, thanks

This is how its done in Firebase v8. by the time of writing the lines the firestore doesnt have a collection called checkout_sessions and this seems to create 1 for each user.uid

```
const docRef = await db
.collection("customers")
.doc(user.uid)
.collection("checkout_sessions").
add({
 price: priceId,
 and: two,
 more: pairs,
});
```

I need to create this same subcollection "checkout_sessions" and add data inside in firebase v9, please thank you!!!!!

Comment: Firestore doesn't have operations for creating collections and subcollections.  You just start writing documents to them, and they will appear in the console.  Are you actually asking how to write a document to a subcollection, regardless of whether or not that's previously been done?

Comment: My friend, I have a collection "customers" which stores each customer under a document (user.uid). Now for each document (user.uid) -> I need to be creating a subcollection called "checkout_sessions" and inserting some data inside. Easiest thing but I'm new and have noone to ask and can't help myself with the official docs :) thanks for the help. I can deliver this code to you in firebase v8 from a tutorial , its just a few lines of code. I am unaware how to translate it to the new v9 structure.

Comment: I am updating my code in the post with 4 lines of firebase v8 code from a tutorial

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Rewriting code to v9 is typically a matter of changing the method calls to the equivalent function calls, and passing in the object as the first parameter.

In your code snippet that'd be:

```
const docRef = doc(db, "customers", user.uid);
const colRef = collection(docRef, "checkout_sessions")
addDoc(colRef, {
 price: priceId,
 and: two,
 more: pairs,
});
```

Answer (score 11):

Just following up on Frank's answer. If you'd like to use setDoc to set a specific id -

```
const docRef = doc(db, "customers", user.uid, "checkout_sessions", "custom id");
setDoc(docRef, {
    price: priceId,
    and: two,
    more: pairs,
 });
```

Comment: To anyone looking here, make sure that the `custom id` is a string. If you happen to put a number there it will throw an error. Seems obvious, but took me a while to debug