# FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field price in document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

Sorry for the noob question, but I am trying to add a document to a subcollection in firestore and I'm struggling.

Following the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551249/firebase-v9-add-subcollection-to-existing-doc) I have done:

```
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid, "checkout_sessions", "custom");
    await setDoc(docRef, {
        test: 10000,
     });
```

Which gives the error:

> FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field price in document users/zoKPWhj36aN7A1ThHe1ja2j83Is2/checkout_sessions/custom)

I simply want to use my page id as the document id in the subcollection, but even passing in a string I am getting errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: The code that you've shared doesn't seem to be throwing the error. Also try restarting the dev server after you've hard coded some values for testing. If you need help with actual issue then please share the exact code that throws the error.

Comment: The error message is saying that some code is trying to add a document using an object that has a property called "price" which is undefined.  That doesn't look related to the code you're showing here, because there is definitely no property called "price" involved.

Comment: Ah, silly me! That was it... Thanks Doug