# TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function error for firebase/firestore v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am receiving a TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function error when trying to access the customers collection in my database. However, I can access the products collection fine.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
   const taskQuery = doc(collection(db, "customers"), where("uid", "==", user.uid))
    const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
        try {
            const taskDocs = await getDocs(taskQuery)

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
```

user.uid is defined and because I can access the 'products' collections, the app initialisation is hooked up correctly. If I remove the 'where("uid"...)' I get a 'Missing or insufficient permissions' error which lead me to believe there is something wrong in the rules.

Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /customers/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;

      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
      match /subscriptions/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;

      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }

      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4UcV.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4UcV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This won't work:

```
const taskQuery = doc(collection(db, "customers"), where("uid", "==", user.uid))
```

The [`doc()` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#doc) expects a db and path to the document, not a set of conditions.

---

If you want to create a query, you should use the [`query` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#query) instead:

```
const taskQuery = query(collection(db, "customers"), where("uid", "==", user.uid))
```

---

I'm pretty sure that also explains the permission denied, as your code likely is trying to read the entire `customers` collection and not just the user's own documents that it is permitted to by your security rules.

Comment: I tried the code as you said, however, I now receive a "missing or insufficient permissions" error. Any ideas on how I should proceed further?

Comment: First off: does my explanation of the first error message you get and why your code causes that make sense? And does it then also make sense how the change I showed in my answer would fix that specific problem? ---

After that... the `allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;` you have on `customers should match the `where("uid", "==", user.uid)` in the code. You might want to remove that condition momentarily to test though. If the problem persists, I recommend posting a new question with just this separate problem.

Comment: Hey frank I was able to solve the issue with the code you provided to another question (slightly modified for my purposes of course. It was this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70551249/firebase-v9-add-subcollection-to-existing-doc. Appreciate the help!